# Angular 5 i18n Pipe Directive Use?

Tags: angular

I have an i18n Pipe, and I cannot figure out how to get it to translate an array item in a template.

Here's the template component:

```js
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({

  selector: 'sa-big-breadcrumbs',
  template: `
   <div><h1 class="page-title txt-color-blueDark">
   <i class="fa-fw fa fa-{{icon}}"></i>{{items[0]}}
   <span *ngFor="let item of items.slice(1)">> {{item}} </span>
</h1></div>
  `,
})
export class BigBreadcrumbsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() public icon: string;
  @Input() public items: Array<string>;


  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here's the HTML that uses the selector:

```html
<div class="row">
  <sa-big-breadcrumbs [items]="['Forum General View']" icon="comment" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-4"></sa-big-breadcrumbs>
  <sa-stats></sa-stats>
</div>
```

I want to translate 'Forum General View', which in the template is

```html
{{items[0]}}
```

I use the pipe without problem in simple string translations, but translating the array item is not something I have been able to solve.

Typically, my translations look like this:

```html
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-comments"></i> {{'Forum' | i18n}}</a>
```

Thanks for helping!

Bob

Comment: Are you talking about localization?

Comment: Yes Kishan, Localization - aka internationalization (i18n).

Answer (score 0):

I'm the OP. It turns out that the i18n Pipe is working fine. The problem was due to the language not being persisted for translation services. Once I fixed the persistence then the pipe works everywhere I need it.

Bob